# How to validate the model, whether it is having particular column or not?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, activesupport-concern

```
class Project
  include Listable
       
  listtable(data_attribute: :verified_at)
end
```

#### Concern

```
module Listable
  class_methods do
    def listable(data_attribute: :verified_at)
      raise ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError, 
        "Must have a verified_at attribute"  unless respond_to?(:verified_at)
    end
  end
end
```

In my
project model i am having column `verified_at`. if i am not having verified_at column in my table it should raise the error.

But here it is not responding properly. always raising the error(even the verified_at is present also)

**Expected**

Wherever i am including this concern in my model, it should check the verified_at column is present or not. If it is not present, should raise the error.

It is not happening for me, Please suggest me any solution, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the model doesn't `respond_to?` in the way you expected it to do.

```
Project.respond_to?(:id)
# false
```

why? because you are asking the class itself if it has the `id` attribute, that only works on an instance.

```
Project.first.respond_to?(:id)
# true
```

To work around this you can take advantage of the `Project.column_names` method, like this.

```
raise ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError, 
    "Must have a verified_at attribute" unless column_names.include?('verified_at')
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Listable` module isn't strictly necessary here. Rails comes with ActiveRecord validations out of the box, something like this will do what you need:

```
class Project
  validates :verified_at, presence: true
end
```

You can then instantiate a `Project` and check if it is valid. If `.valid?` returns false, it cannot be saved to the Database:

```
project = Project.new
=> #<Project:0x00007ff3aec268a8
 id: nil,
 verified_at: nil,
 created_at: nil,
 updated_at: nil>
project.valid?
=> false
project.save!
=> ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Verified At can't be blank

project = Project.new(verified_at: Time.zone.now)
=> #<Project:0x00007ff3aec268a8
 id: nil,
 verified_at: Mon, 11 Jan 2021 04:09:24 EST -05:00,
 created_at: nil,
 updated_at: nil>
project.valid?
=> true
project.save!
#  DB query
=> true
```

Some reading: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html

Comment: That checks if the `verified_at` has a value, the question is about checking whether the field/column itself is in the db